# Using Context crashes app, Activity is fine? onAttach

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I just started to learn about Android Developing a day ago, and I was watching the youtuber Bucky. He was using onAttach(Activity activity), but well since his video is from two years ago this method deprecated, so I need need to use the onAttach(Context context).
Thing is, when using Activity, the app runs just fine although when I use Context, it just crashes whenever I press the Button.
How can I fix this?

**Errors:**

```
01-29 22:28:59.156 5854-5854/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NullPointerException
         at com.jruivo.mymemegenerator.TopSectionFragment.buttonClicked(TopSectionFragment.java:53)
         at com.jruivo.mymemegenerator.TopSectionFragment.access$000(TopSectionFragment.java:15)
         at com.jruivo.mymemegenerator.TopSectionFragment$1.onClick(TopSectionFragment.java:45)
```

**TopSectionFragment Class:**

```
public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static EditText topTextInput;
    private static EditText bottomTextInput;

    TopSectionListener activityCommander;

    public interface TopSectionListener {
        public void createMeme(String top, String bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);
        topTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.topTextInput);
        bottomTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomTextInput);
        final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void buttonClicked(View v) {
        activityCommander.createMeme(topTextInput.getText().toString(), bottomTextInput.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Edit: changed "knap" to "button", was a mistake while copying my code to here.

Comment: Sidenote: since `buttonClicked(View v)` is just a redirection, you could place that code directly into `onClick(View v)`

Comment: static view vairables in a fragment are a sign that your achitecture is really wrong.  There's no good reason to ever do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GabeSechan , I literally copy pasted the code from the guy from the video, but I'll take that into account on my training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because your Android device is not API 23+ and the version of the method you are using was added in API 23.

You either need to override the `onAttach` that takes an `Activity` or switch to using the support library that includes the support fragment manager and fragments. That should correctly call onAttach(Context context) even on pre API 23 devices.

You can try proving to yourself you are not reaching `onAttach(Context context)` by writing something to logcat using `Log.d(...)` in that method.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is knapp.set.... change it to button and functionality should be fine.

```
final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(View v) {
                                 buttonClicked(v);
                             }
                         }
);
```

You're using the variable `knapp` which is not initialized, thus a NullPointerException appears.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot to edit the "knapp" to button before copying it here.
Though it still crashes , even changing it to button

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointer is due to the `knapp` variable that does not seem to be initialised - hence the exception.

Change `knapp.setOnClickListener` to `button.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, I forgot to change that to button heh. Still after changing that, it still crashes the app.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your activity implements `TopSectionListener`. If so, try this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);

    try {
        activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }

    topTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.topTextInput);
    bottomTextInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomTextInput);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 buttonClicked(v);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And remove these lines,

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I swapped the imports and it's now working properly.. I don't know if this is the correct way.

**From**:
import android.app.Fragment;

**To:**
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;